# Correct model to use in travel speed analysis

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am attempting to analyse downstream travel speed of fish within two different rivers, however, I am getting lost on which model I should use. Please see working below

data:

```
data4<-structure(list(code = structure(1:32, .Label = c("10888", "10889", 
"10890", "10891", "10892", "10893", "10894", "10896", "10897", 
"10898", "10899", "10900", "10901", "10902", "10903", "10904", 
"10905", "10906", "10907", "10908", "10909", "10910", "10914", 
"10916", "10917", "10919", "10920", "10922", "10923", "10924", 
"10925", "10927"), class = "factor"), speed = c(0.0296315046039244, 
0.0366986630049636, 0.0294297725505692, 0.048316183511095, 0.0294275666501456, 
0.199924957584131, 0.0798850288176711, 0.0445886457047146, 0.0285993712316451, 
0.0715158276875623, 1.53078364415863, 1.32386730007184, 0.0879404548120395, 
0.0884436446391665, 0.142680147253483, 0.256122292011316, 0.029228002169911, 
0.0535706245570686, 0.0268752274519418, 0.238146999654007, 0.424175803745118, 
0.021181456637386, 0.0337364380380858, 0.030136111418826, 0.0335130031085068, 
0.148793370546863, 0.096737574741185, 0.114746050390462, 0.0993760102817675, 
0.0985453244761994, 0.100223001228893, 0.0924775724221547), meanflow =       c(0.657410742496051, 
0.608271363339857, 0.663241108786611, 0.538259450171821, 0.666299529534762, 
0.507156583629893, 0.762448863636364, 37.6559178370787, 50.8557196935557, 
31.6601587837838, 225.109658536585, 230.452020833333, 106.450571428571, 
106.51658356546, 26.6998648648649, 22.6653709677419, 0.667544935064935, 
0.803912464319696, 0.660643403441683, 58.1045714285714, 164.84368, 
63.5970920920921, 50.7789043570669, 47.3644579971523, 45.6948401055409, 
0.808431216931217, 0.612270689655172, 46.4646057866184, 0.605024778761062, 
0.6091, 0.601483928571429, 0.616563426688633), length = c(136, 
157, 132, 140, 135, 134, 144, 149, 139, 165, 155, 143, 144, 143, 
156, 147, 133, 131, 129, 143, 140, 125, 140, 140, 147, 120, 115, 
139, 123, 120, 125, 136), river = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("c", 
"f"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("code", "speed", "meanflow", 
"length", "river"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 4L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 
32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 
60L, 62L, 64L, 68L))
```

I would like to look at the effect of specific variables on travel speed, particularly to see if travel speed is different between rivers.

Fixed effects: river, length

Interaction: An interaction between river and length is considered and added as a fixed effect due to fish swimming in slower currents, and body length having a direct impact on swimspeed. currents differ between river and so length will have greater impact on rivers with slower currents

So:

```
model1 <-lm(speed ~ 1 + river + length + river: length, data = data4)
```

However 'meanflow' has a direct impact on travel speed as a higher flow will enable fish to swim quicker downstream. To account for this I believe this should be added as a random effect?!

And be like:

```
library(lme4)
model2<- lmer(speed ~ river + length + river:length + (1|meanflow), data = data4)
```

Yet this does not run as 'meanflow' is a continuous variable. would I be better to dis regard this variable, or maybe use a different model all together

Any help would be great

Comment: I don't like the fixed/random terminology. Here, the variable that is repeated is not meanflow but river. The fish in a particular river will be more similar (at least possibly) than fish across rivers. So, I think you have meanflow and river reversed in your lme code.

Comment: Yes I understand that fish in each river will be more closely related. I maybe did not make clear, 'meanflow' is the mean flow calculated for the duration under which travel time was also calculated. This is to take into account fish travelling in flood conditions as opposed to those travelling other flow conditions. The flow between the two rivers is very different and so there is an interaction between river and flow, so possibly 'meanflow:river' should be added in?

Comment: Possibly. You can certainly look at it. But the key is that river is the variable that is repeated.

Comment: something like this would be more appropriate?:           model2<- lmer(speed ~ meanflow + length + meanflow:length + (1|river), data = data4)

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Agree with Peter that your second try is better.  However, you won't be able to make explicit statistical comparisons between rivers (i.e. hypothesis tests of differences between rivers), just characterize the among-river variance.  You might want to consider `speed~meanflow*length+(length|river)` (i.e. the effect of length varies across rivers even once `meanflow` is taken into account)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for this. Trying to understand this more. meanflow*speed indicates an interaction. I am not completely sure what the second piece means, is that nested within the interaction? and would that allow for statistical comparisons between rivers?